# 'Main process exited' error Gunicorn systemd file

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I follow this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04) to deploy my Django project. I created `gunicorn.service` file in `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service` with this configuration:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=azizbek
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/admin/respositories/ninersComingSoon
ExecStart=/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/ninersComingSoon-_UZsUc5R/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/admin/repositories/ninersComingSoon/niners.sock ninersComingSoon.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Location of my project is `/home/admin/respositories/ninersComingSoon`

And when I run

```
systemctl start gunicorn
systemctl enable gunicorn
```

it must create `niners.sock` file inside the project directory but it doesn't.

Then I typed this command to figure out what I did wrong.

```
journalctl -u gunicorn
```

And the result was

```
Dec 05 02:05:26 server.niners.uz systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Dec 05 02:05:26 server.niners.uz systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Dec 05 02:05:26 server.niners.uz systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 05 02:05:26 server.niners.uz systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

So can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried running the `ExecStart` command manually on the command line? You might find that throws up some error that's being suppressed when you run via `systemctl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in `WorkingDirectory`. There was an incorrect path. There should be `.../repositories/...` instead of `.../respositories/...`